# Invalid attempt to read data even when data is present in SqlDataReader in vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, winforms

Here's my code which gives error, the query returns value for the particular item.

Also in the database side the query return rows even I have put condition that if reader has rows then only assign it to a variable but still it throws an error eg.

```
dqty = sqlreader("qty")
```

Code:

```
Private Function checkquantity(ByVal code As String, ByVal quan As Integer) As Boolean
    sqlcommand.CommandText = "select sum(qty) as qty from pos_stock_balance where item_code='" & code & "'"
    sqlcommand.Connection = AppsCon
    sqlreader = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader
    If sqlreader.HasRows Then

        dqty = sqlreader("qty")
        sqlreader.Close()

    Else
        sqlreader.Close()
    End If
    If quan > dqty Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True

    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because you are directly accessing the data without reading it, Try this,

```
If sqlreader.HasRows Then
      If sqlreader.read()
        dqty = sqlreader("qty")
        sqlreader.Close()
       End If
Else
       sqlreader.Close()
End If
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

---

**Cleaned version** of your code,

```
Private Function checkquantity _
(ByVal code As String, ByVal quan As Integer) As Boolean

    try

    sqlcommand.CommandText = "select" _
    & "sum(qty) as qty from pos_stock_balance where item_code='" & code & "'"

    sqlcommand.Connection = AppsCon
    sqlreader = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader

    If sqlreader.read() Then
         dqty = sqlreader("qty")
    End If

    If quan > dqty Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If

    Finally
       sqlreader.Close()
    End try

End Function
```

Although i cleaned your code, Your code is still vulnerable to [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Try to use parameterised queries to avoid that

Comment: @Ric Catch is optional.

Comment: Fair enough, thought you may want to do something should en exception get raised. Nevermind.

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy :could you tell me in detail difference between sqlreader.hasrows and sqlreader.read

Comment: @vimalvasudevan I hope this link will clarify you doubt. http://forums.asp.net/t/1175522.aspx

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed to insert the record.

Answer (score 2):

If you are simply returning a scalar value use:

```
dqty = CType(sqlcommand.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)
...
If quan > dqty Then
    Return False
Else
    Return True    
End If
```

This returns an `object` which can be casted to the necessary type allowing your comparisons at the end of the code to continue as normal without the need for a `SqlDataReader` at all.
But beware that as your sql is not wrapped in an `ISNULL()`, the value returned could be null  in which case you may wish to check for this.
As a further note, use parameterized queries!

Comment: i saw your answer now.i had already voted for that answer and after that yours i got update now..well both answers satifsy my question and well yours allows me to remove unnecessary declarations and code..well its a matter of choice...i cant mark both as answers right ric.. well thanks for the support answer dear....